# Why isn't tensorflow-gpu==1.13.1 available?

Tags: python, tensorflow

In my requirements.txt, I have:

```
tensorflow-gpu==1.13.1
```

And when I ran:

```
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

I saw this error:

```
Collecting tensorflow-gpu==1.13.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 35))
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-gpu==1.13.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 35)) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow-gpu==1.13.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 35))
You are using pip version 19.0.3, however version 20.3b1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Why I can't install it?

Comment: which python version are you using?

Comment: I am using python3.

Comment: TensorFlow dropped the support of versions 1.* in python 3.8.try working with python 3.7 or 3.6 instead

Comment: To install tensorflow-gpu==1.13 https://betterprogramming.pub/install-tensorflow-1-13-on-ubuntu-18-04-with-gpu-support-239b36d29070

Comment: To install tensorflow-gpu==1.13 Refer: <br>
https://betterprogramming.pub/install-tensorflow-1-13-on-ubuntu-18-04-with-gpu-support-239b36d29070

Answer (score 1):

As @Mahmood Kiaheyrati pointed out for Python 3.8+ supported versions are 2.2+ as the error traceback shows. Complete error traceback on `python3.8.6` follows

```
pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.13.1
>>> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-gpu==1.13.1 (from versions: 2.2.0rc1, 2.2.0rc2, 2.2.0rc3, 2.2.0rc4, 2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.3.0rc0, 2.3.0rc1, 2.3.0rc2, 2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.4.0rc0, 2.4.0rc1, 2.4.0rc2, 2.4.0rc3)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-gpu==1.13.1
```

Consider Python version 3.7 or 3.6. Expected message for this versions

```
Collecting tensorflow-gpu==1.13.1
  Downloading 
  ....
Successfully installed
...
tensorflow-gpu-1.13.1
```

Comment: However, my python version is Python 3.7.3 (default, Dec 13 2019, 19:58:14) , from which I created a virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

I have just encountered the same issue also. Since `tensorflow-1.x` is supported by `python3.6` kind of versions, and your default python version is higher than that (in my case python3.9) `pip install` can not find the compatible version.

Solution is simple and tricky. Just use the pip install by python3.6(or other compatible versions) with the command:

```
python3.6 -m pip install tensorflow==1.13.2
```

and run the script with specified python version:

```
python3.6 main.py
```